# Keep order of Immutable JS Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a JavaScript Array looking like this

```
const data = 
[
   {
       id: 19,
       date: 01.01.2001,
       content: ...
   },
   {
       id: 85,
       date: 10.10.2002,
       content: ...
   },
   {
       id: 1113,
       date: 07.09.2018,
       content: ...
   },
   ...
];
```

Originally, `data` is unsorted when it comes from the server. I sort `data` by `date`, keeping it in an `array` to preserve its order.

```
const data = 
[
   {
       id: 1113,
       date: 07.09.2018,
       content: ...
   },
   {
       id: 85,
       date: 10.10.2002,
       content: ...
   },
   {
       id: 19,
       date: 01.01.2001,
       content: ...
   },
   ...
];
```

However, accessing an element with an `id`, will result in iteration over the whole array. Storing them in an `object` with this structure

```
const obj = 
{
    19: {
            date: 01.01.2001,
            content: ...,
         },
    85: {
            date: 10.10.2002,
            content: ....,
        },
    1113: {
            date; 07.09.2018,
            content: ...
          }
}
```

will make the access easier, but it will not be sorted. 
I am looking for a Immutable JS way to store the data in an `Map`, like `obj`, but keeping its order but `date`. The `key` is supposed to be the `id`.

How do I sort by `date`, but keep `id` as `key`?

Comment: "but that one has performance problems" --- isn't it because of the very reason of storing the original order as well?

Comment: @zerkms sorry, I edited my Q.

Comment: Now you don't have a question

Comment: If you are changing the way the object is constructed to make it faster to pull out the data you need, why do you care what order it's in?

Comment: @zerkms I thought that is obvious. Added a sentence with a questionmark

Comment: I thought the answer is also obvious then: You cannot, immutablejs `Map` or native JS objects do not retain order.

Comment: Why do you need to order it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you've already solved this by now. But **Immutable.orderedMap** seems to be a perfect solution fo you.

https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap

Answer (score 1):

Myp by itself is unsorted.   Maybe you could keep your objects in array,  and build a map for quick access (maybe in the lazy way, or eager iterating over the array once). Best solution depends on amount of data and what you are doing with  it